# Thinned counting process and inter-arrival distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

$N(t)$ is a renewal process with inter-arrival distribution $F$, and the distribution of the $n$th arrival time is $F_n$. Each arrival is erased independently with probability $0 < p < 1$, and the process of arrivals that are not erased gives rise to a new counting process $\tilde{N}(t)$. Write $M(t) = \tilde{N}(t/(1-p))$. How do I go about finding the inter-arrival distribution for the counting process $M(t)$?

Comment: This is the concatenation of two different, unrelated, problems: how to deduce the inter-arrival distribution of $\tilde N$ from the i.-a.dist. of $N$; how to deduce the i.-a.dist. of $M$ from the i.-a.dist. of $\tilde N$. What are your ideas on each?

Comment: @Did I know that $\tilde{N}$ is essentially a splitting process of $N$, and I understand this idea in the case of Poisson processes. For general inter-arrival distributions, I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$, $S$ and $R$ denote some random variables distributed like the inter-arrival times of $N$, $\tilde N$ and $M$ respectively. Each inter-arrival time of $\tilde N$ is the sum of a geometrical number of independent inter-arrival times of $N$ hence their common CDF $G$ is such that, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$
G(t)=P[S\leqslant t]=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(1-p)p^{n-1}F^{\ast n}(t),\qquad F(t)=P[T\leqslant t].
$$
One deduces $M$ from $\tilde N$ through a dilation of time hence the CDF $H$ of its inter-arrival times is such that, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$
H(t)=P[R\leqslant t]=G(t/(1-p)).
$$
The Laplace transforms of the inter-arrival times may be easier to handle and are as follows. For every $u\geqslant0$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{-uS}]=\sum_{n\geqslant1}(1-p)p^{n-1}E[\mathrm e^{-uT}]^n=\frac{(1-p)E[\mathrm e^{-uT}]}{1-pE[\mathrm e^{-uT}]}.
$$
Likewise, for every $u\geqslant0$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{-uR}]=E[\mathrm e^{-u(1-p)S}].
$$
In particular,
$$
E[T]=(1-p)E[S]=E[R].
$$